# How to use Feather Icons in XPages?

Tags: javascript, xpages, feathericons

I already tried using the CDN version, adding the feather.min.js file locally and even copy-pasting the script in the xpage output script control but still I'm getting an Uncaught ReferenceError: feather... when I call feather.replace().

Comment: Feather uses AMD loader which conflict with Dojo in XPages. Search for other XPages questions on how to solve this :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot @PerHenrikLausten! Didn't expect to have someone still answer XPages questions! I opted to use fontawesome instead. I don't want to spend too much time resolving this just for icons.